# Substring comparison with an equals sign in Batch

Tags: string, batch-file, url

My batch script gets a url passed into it with a number of query params, one of which will be `browser=chrom`e, `browser=firefox` etc.

I'm trying to do a substring comparison to check if it has `browser=chrome` in the url:

```
if not "x%url:browser=chrome=%"=="x%url%" (
    start chrome
)
```

This doesn't seem to work, I think because of how batch reads = signs, any ideas how I can do this? I can't just check for "chrome" as this could occer elsewhere in the query params.

Comment: `echo %url% | find /i "browser=chrome" || start chrome`

Comment: Nice, I do get some errors like `find /i: No such file or directory`, but it does seem to work, and then do you know how I could get `exit 0` to run if browser=chrome is in the string?